# Webpage in Iframe is showing without css?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I have an IFRAME in a page. And i have loaded another web page in that IFRAME.
But this newly added web page is not showing properly, i.e., web page is displaying without css.

If i open same web page in another window it displays normally with css.
I have searched a lot but haven't found any solution to resolve it.

Any Suggestions,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is the webpage from another domain?
2. Does the webpage of the iframe start with http while the parent page is https? Make sure the protocols are the same.

Comment: Yes the webpage is from another domain and protcol of parent page is http and that of iframe is https.

Comment: I came to know that some websites do not allow its content to display in a iframe